# Why is the return value of pthread_join() not changing with each call to pthread_join()

Tags: c, multithreading, void-pointers, prime-factoring, pthread-join

This program works fine if the user enters only 1 number on the command line. It will factor out the prime factors and output them to the console just fine.

```
J_10542741@cs3060:~/assn3$ ./assn3 12
12: 2, 2, 3,
```

My problem is when I test it on these two other cases:

A) Multiple Arguments:

```
J_10542741@cs3060:~/assn3$ ./assn3 10 8 6
10: 2, 5,
8: 2, 5,
6: 2, 5,
```

B) Using a Range of Numbers (i.e. {1..5}):

```
J_10542741@cs3060:~/assn3$ ./assn3 {1..5}
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
```

I've looked around this site for anything regarding the return value of pthread_join() as well as searching through Google. I feel that it's a problem with this part of my code:

```
 // FOR loop to join each thread w/ Main Thread 1x1
    for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
            retCode = pthread_join(t_id[i], &factors);
            results = factors;
            if (retCode != 0){
                    // Print Error Message and return -1
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failure to join threads.");
                    return -1;
            }
            else{
                    printf("%s: ", argv[i+1]);
                    while(*results != 0){
                            printf("%d, ", *results);
                            results++;
                    }
            }
            free(factors);
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>

// Return a pointer to the pFactors array
void *primeFactors(void* number){
    int *pFactors = malloc(sizeof(int));    // Dynamic Array for prime factors

    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 1;
    int num = atoi((char*)number);
    int prime = 2;

    // If num < 4, then that number is already prime
    if(num < 4)
            pFactors[capacity] = num;
    else{
            while(num > 1){
                    while(num % prime == 0){
                            if(capacity == size){
                                    size++;
                                    pFactors = realloc(pFactors, size*sizeof(int));
                            }
                            num /= prime;
                            pFactors[capacity] = prime;
                            capacity++;
                    }
                    prime++;
            }
    }
    if(capacity == size){
            size++;
            pFactors = realloc(pFactors, size*sizeof(int));
    }
    pFactors[capacity] = 0;
    pthread_exit((void*)pFactors);
}

// MAIN FUNCTION
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i, retCode;         // retCode holds the value of successful/fail operation for pthread_create/join
    int j = 1;

    int* results;
    void* factors;

    //Thread Identifier value is equal to the number of actual int(s) in argv
    pthread_t t_id[argc-1];

    // Check argc for too few arguments
    if(argc < 2){
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./assn3 <integer value>...");
            return -1;
    }

    // Loop through argv and check argv[j] value to ensure it's >= 0
    while(j <= argc-1){
            if(atoi(argv[j]) < 0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0", atoi(argv[j]));
                    return -1;
            }
            j++;
    }

    // Create the thread
    for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
            retCode = pthread_create(&t_id[i], NULL, primeFactors, *(argv+1));
            if (retCode != 0){
                    // Print Error Message and return -1
                    printf("Failure to start thread. Error: %d\n", retCode);
                    return -1;
            }
    }

    // FOR loop to join each thread w/ Main Thread 1x1
    for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
            retCode = pthread_join(t_id[i], &factors);
            results = factors;
            if (retCode != 0){
                    // Print Error Message and return -1
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failure to join threads.");
                    return -1;
            }
            else{
                    printf("%s: ", argv[i+1]);
                    while(*results != 0){
                            printf("%d, ", *results);
                            results++;
                    }
            }
            free(factors);
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To reiterate, this program works fine if I only enter in 1 argument. However, when there are multiple arguments, the program outputs the prime factors of the first argument correctly but the following arguments are printed with the prime factors of the first argument. Secondly, when you input a bash script range (i.e.{1..5}) it only prints out the arguments and not their respective prime factors. If there's something that needs clarification, feel free to ask. Also if there appears to be a duplicate/similar question(s) somewhere that I haven't been able to find, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pthread_create(&t_id[i], NULL, primeFactors, *(argv+1))
```

You are passing the same argument, `*(argv+1)`, to every thread. Try with `*(argv+1+i)` instead.

Comment: And for the problem with `{1..5}` as an argument, there's a bug in how `primeFactors()` handles the `pFactors` array when `(num < 4)`.

Comment: Thanks kaylum! I didn't see that earlier. I guess I've been staring too long at the screen to have seen it earlier.

Comment: Thank you Michael Burr. I'll see what I can do about it to get it to work hopefully.

Comment: I got the bug fixed for handling `(num < 4)`. I had forgotten to add `capacity++` after adding the number to the array.